# spark + kafka inputstream "spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition"

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, apache-kafka, inputstream

Setting spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition:100 and ingesting the 10000 records , it should take 100 records per second ,
but consumes all 10000 records